# Use custom sitemap provider

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have created my custom sitemap provider by inheriting a StaticSiteMapProvider class and registered it in a web.config.
How can use that provider to display sitemap in xml format so google can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about StaticSiteMapProvider, but recently I was using steb-by-step instructions from [this](http://www.how-to-asp.net/generate-submit-sitemap/) great article to generate xml sitemap and ping google, yahoo, bing and ask with it. Hope it can help you as well.